# Единый механизм обратимого шифрования в PHP и JS

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Возникла задача шифровать передаваемые данные между сервером и клиентом с помощью ключа без использования https (ключ передаётся отдельно, это другая история).
Так вот. Интересует сам механизм. Знаю, что в JS нет встроенных функций шифрования, а в PHP их много, но не все нормально декодируют UTF8.

Вопрос: есть ли готовые решения (если можно с примерами) такой задачи?

Comment: можно использовать xor. A^B. Первый раз зашифрует, второй - расшифрует.

Comment: http://www.navioo.com/javascript/dhtml/DES_in_JavaScript_1163.html
http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AES](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) реализация [на JS](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html) и [на PHP](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes-php.html).

Answer (score 0):

Может быть [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130085/) или [это](http://javascript.ru/php/base64_decode) или [это](http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms) поможет, а [это](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html) так вообще похоже ответ на ваш вопрос, да и вот еще если потребуется выполнить запрос GET с параметрами, мы должны будем включить их в URL в виде строки запроса, но при этом на наши плечи ложится вся ответственность за правильность оформления строки запроса и кодирования имен и значений параметров. Для этого можно использовать удобный метод JavaScript [encodeURIComponent()](http://javascript.ru/encodeURIComponent) или вспомогательную функцию jQuery [$.param()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_url). На стороне сервера будут работать функции PHP *rawurldecode*, *rawurlencode*, *urldecode*, *urlencode*